# I got success to get a new facebook access token for long time 60 days . How can i test/check that it is for 60 days?

Tags: c#, facebook, winforms

This is the method:

```
public static string RenewToken(string existingToken)
        {
            var fb = new FacebookClient();
            dynamic result = fb.Get("oauth/access_token",
                                    new
                                    {
                                        client_id = 137,
                                        client_secret = "a45",
                                        grant_type = "fb_exchange_token",
                                        fb_exchange_token = existingToken
                                    });

            return result.access_token;
        }
```

And in the top of the form i have two variables:

```
string ShortaccessToken
string LongaccessToken
```

The first contain the old/working short time access token.
The second contain the new/working long time access token code.

And i use it in my constructor used it once:

```
RenewToken(ShortaccessToken);
```

And got the new one token code and im using in my code now the long one variable and its working its posting.

But my question is now how can i check/find untill when my new access token code will work ? When it will expire what date ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can verify this by calling:

```
GET /debug_token?input_token={input-token}&access_token={access-token}
```

Where {access-token} is your App Access Token, as described here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/#debug

Check the contents of the **expires_at** field.